# use graph api on php to get video data from facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I need load all videos data from a facebook page use graph api. How do this in php code?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [Facebook FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) for [Querying Video Table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/). Hope it helps

**Edited**

To read video you need:

- Any valid access_token for publicly available videos
- user_videos permissions for all videos owned by the user (including nonpublic videos)
- friend_videos permissions for videos owned by the user's friends

See this example for more detail for getting [Valid Access Token](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)

Comment: i try with this query ='SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=PAGE_ID'. but not all video as result (i have 11 videos in my facebook page,8 posted by admin and 3 posted by public user )
'

Comment: yes, i already use php-sdk in my code. Below complete code from me
require 'fb-sdk/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'AP_ID',
  'secret' => 'SECRET_CODE',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));
query ='SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=PAGE_ID'
$param  =   array(
 'method'    => 'fql.query',
 'query'     => $fql,
 'callback'  => ''
);    what's wrong with me?? thx for your help again..